# WebAPI controller date format frombody

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, datetime-format

I have a POCO DTO class that has a date field on it. And I have a form on a web page in Portuguese (`dd/mm/yyyy`). When the data is posted from de form, the API controller receives the date field in `mm/dd/yyyy` format. I've already put some culture settings in the `web.config` and `global.asax`, but it had no effect.

Inspecting the posted values whith chrome developer tools I can see that the date is correct: 01/07/1983. But in the api controller it turns 07/01/1983.

What's the correct way to configure the controller so it could receive the correct date format?

Comment: you should use Chome developer tools to take a look and see what is actually being sent over to your controller method.
It could just be, the debugger is showing it to you that way.
Why dont you just format the date inside the controller method to be the way you want it?

Comment: What's the problem of having it in mm/dd/yyyy? you could always set it to the correct format at the end right?

Comment: You should handle the sending/receiving of all date & datetime instances in [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The client should display the date as it sees fit, this is presentation logic and falls outside of the actual sending/receiving of the date instance.

Comment: +1 to @Igor's suggestion. His suggestion will make it easier to support  users of the app with different localization settings which is the issue you are running into.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help!

I solved this by putting in Web.config:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR"/>
```

And in Application_Start in Global.asax.cs:

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.Culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```

Comment: Worked gracefully... in my case I didnt set requestEncoding nor responseEncoding cuz of the acents...